Am I seeing only half of the whole picture in linear differential systems?
When one studies systems of linear differential equations with constant coefficients, for example systems of the form
$$\begin{cases}
 \dot x = ax + by \\
 \dot y = cx + dy 
\end{cases}
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
\dot v = Av
$$
where $A$ is some square matrix, one immediately is confronted with a classification of phase space portraits based on the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$, and goes on discussing stability based on the real part of these eigenvalues.
I've been always bothered by the omission of the case in which both eigenvalues are complex but not conjugate. Of course in this case we would be dealing with a complex-valued system of ODEs.
My gut feeling is telling me that something beautiful and hidden is happening there, in a similar sense that every different conic in the affine space is essentially the same conic in projective geometry, but I don't know what to look for to begin this study.
My question is: what happens if the matrix $A$ has complex values? The solution of the differential system will then be complex valued and the phase portraits may not be visualizable, but wouldn't it be interesting to get the whole picture in a single theoretical framework, possibly with some unifying geometry in the background? If this is the case, where should I begin to study this topic?

The main difference in the case you describe is that there are now no purely real trajectories. One can take the phase space to be $\mathbb{C}^2\cong \mathbb{R}^4$ in this case, while in the case of a real matrix $A$ one can still take the phase space to be $\mathbb{C}^2$, but also it is possible to consider it to be $\mathbb{R}^2$. This makes a big difference if you want to draw phase portraits on paper of course.
Regardless of whether the two eigenvalues are complex conjugates, the stability will depend on the real part, and whether one is non-negative making the system unstable, or both are negative making it stable.

I'd be really amazed if there would be some beautiful underlying unifying geometry to these systems...is there any?
